# convert string into array which is enclosed with "[" and "]" brackets using apex

Tags: apex

[[[456,33.67],[-79.61464,33.037796],[-79.616384,33.037403],[-79.618335,33.03631]]]

Hello Guys - I have a string like the above and **its not an array**. I just need to get the fist pair and the last pair in the string using apex code?

I.E. I need only the fist and last values in a list.

like [456,33.67] 0th element
and [-79.618335,33.03631] the last in the list.

Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that you always get the results in the same format. If not, you will have to handle all the possible scenarios in which you can get the result.

For the above scenario, if you get the results in this specified consistent format, then below code should work for you

```
string str ='[[[456,33.67],[-79.61464,33.037796],[-79.616384,33.037403],[-79.618335,33.03631]]]';
List<string> strArray = str.split('],');
string firstString=''; 
string lastString ='';
if(strArray.size()>0){
    firstString = strArray[0].replace('[','').replace(']','');
    lastString = strArray[strArray.size()-1].replace('[','').replace(']','');
}
firstString = '[' + firstString + ']';
lastString = '[' + lastString + ']';
```

Comment: Hi @HarishSridhar, That's great !! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.